# Get id of motherboard and hard disk in java for linux operating system?

Tags: java, linux

Good afternoon, I wonder what would be the correct way to find the serial number of hard disk and matherboard a PC with Linux operating system using java code.

Use the

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime () exec ("hdparm-I / dev / sda | grep Serial")
```

command,. To get the hard disk, but the command is not executed.

Could help me? Thanks Greetings!

Comment: You forget a `.` in `getRuntime () exec` and also a `;` at the last.

Comment: It might not worth the effort: a motivated hacker could patch his kernel to fake that information.....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a shell pipeline from Java you have to explicitly invoke the shell (i.e. bash) and pass it the command to be executed.  `Runtime#exec()` does not invoke the shell unless you tell it to.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c\"hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

> Matherboard

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "bios", "get", "serialnumber" });

```
    process.getOutputStream().close();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    String property = sc.next();
    String serial = sc.next();
    System.out.println(property + ": " + serial);
```

> HardDisk

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "diskdrive", "get", "serialnumber" });

```
    process.getOutputStream().close();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    String property = sc.next();
    String serial = sc.next();
    System.out.println(property + ": " + serial);
```